# I can't manage to get into a second recursive call Prolog

Tags: prolog

I am building a Guess Who alike command line game in Prolog. It works calling a function named jugar/0, which inside itself calls a recursive predicate called game/8, which is the actual game loop. Whenever I try to play a game the first turn works just right, but when it ends, it repeats some of the stuff it did on jugar/0 and never goes inside the second player turn. Here is my full code:

```
%---------------------------------------------------------
%==============================================
%              Condition Settings
%==============================================
%Sexo
chico('Albert').
chico('Paul').
chico('Tom').
chico('Derek').
chico('Richard').
chico('Louis').
chico('Michael').
chico('Charles').
chico('Sam').
chico('Steve').
chico('Will').
chico('Anthony').
chico('Billy').
chico('Henry').
chica('Tiffany').
chica('Natalie').
chica('Roxanne').
chica('Sarah').
chica('Sabrina').
chica('Cindy').
chica('Emma').
gafas('Emma').
gafas('Derek').
gafas('Louis').
gafas('Roxanne').
%==============================================
%              END/Condition Settings
%==============================================
%---------------------------------------------------------
%---------------------------------------------------------
%==============================================
%              Auxiliar Predicates
%==============================================
  %Prints every element of a list
    printList([X|L]):-
      write('\t'),
      writeln(X),
      printList(L).
    printList([]).
  %Creates newList with elements of L that satisfy C
  %satisfies(L,C,NewList).
    satisfies([],_,[]).
    satisfies([H|T],C,[H|R]):- call(C,H),satisfies(T,C,R).
    satisfies([H|T],C,R):-not(call(C,H)),satisfies(T,C,R).
  %Same as above but with negative condition
  %Creates newList with elements of L that satisfy not(C)
  %nsatisfies(L,C,NewList).
    nsatisfies([],_,[]).
    nsatisfies([H|T],C,R):-call(C,H),nsatisfies(T,C,R).
    nsatisfies([H|T],C,[H|R]):- not(call(C,H)),nsatisfies(T,C,R).
  %Auxiliar predicate to choose gaming mode
    esmodo('PVP').
    esmodo('PVE').

    modo(X):-
      write('seleccione modo de juego: '),
      nl,
      read(X),
      esmodo(X).
  %Copies L into T
  %copy(L,T)
    copy(L,T):- L = T.
  %Chooses the character with which a player will have to play
    chooseCharacter(X):-
      random_member(X,['Albert','Paul','Tom','Derek','Richard','Louis','Michael','Charles','Sam','Steve','Will','Anthony','Billy','Henry','Tiffany','Natalie','Roxanne','Sarah','Sabrina','Cindy','Emma']).
  %Creates the neccesary lists to begin the game
    createList(Options,Man,Women) :-
     Man = ['Albert','Paul','Tom','Derek','Richard','Louis','Michael','Charles','Sam','Steve','Will','Anthony','Billy','Henry'],
     Women = ['Tiffany','Natalie','Roxanne','Sarah','Sabrina','Cindy','Emma'],
     append(Man,Women,Options).
  %Creates Conditions List
    conditionList(Conditions):- Conditions = [chico,chica,gafas].
%==============================================
%              END/Auxiliar Predicates
%==============================================
%---------------------------------------------------------

%( condition -> then_clause ; else_clause )
game('PVP',Options1,Options2,Conditions1,Conditions2,Jug1,Jug2,Player):-
    (Player =:= 1 ->
        writeln('Turno del jugador 1'),
        writeln('Preguntas restantes: '),
        %printList(Conditions),
        writeln('Elija su pregunta: '),
        read(Pregunta),

        (Pregunta = 'chico' -> (
          chico(Jug2) ->
            writeln('Correcto'),writeln('Personajes restantes: '), satisfies(Options1,chico,ResultOptions), writeln(ResultOptions),delete(chico,Conditions,ResultConditions),writeln(ResultConditions),game('PVP',ResultOptions,Options2,ResultConditions,Conditions2,Jug1,Jug2,2);
            writeln('Error'),writeln('Personajes restantes: '), satisfies(Options1,chica,ResultOptions), writeln(ResultOptions),delete(chico,Conditions,ResultConditions),writeln(ResultConditions),game('PVP',ResultOptions,Options2,ResultConditions,Conditions2,Jug1,Jug2,2));
        (Pregunta = 'chica' -> (
          chica(Jug2) ->
            writeln('Correcto'),writeln('Personajes restantes: '), satisfies(Options1,chica,ResultOptions), writeln(ResultOptions),delete(chica,Conditions,ResultConditions),writeln(ResultConditions),game('PVP',ResultOptions,Options2,ResultConditions,Conditions2,Jug1,Jug2,2);
            writeln('Error'),writeln('Personajes restantes: '), satisfies(Options1,chico,ResultOptions), writeln(ResultOptions),delete(chica,Conditions,ResultConditions),writeln(ResultConditions),game('PVP',ResultOptions,Options2,ResultConditions,Conditions2,Jug1,Jug2,2));
        (Pregunta = 'gafas' -> (
          gafas(Jug2) ->
            writeln('Correcto'),writeln('Personajes restantes: '), satisfies(Options1,gafas,ResultOptions), writeln(ResultOptions),delete(gafas,Conditions,ResultConditions),writeln(ResultConditions),game('PVP',ResultOptions,Options2,ResultConditions,Conditions2,Jug1,Jug2,2);
            writeln('Error'),writeln('Personajes restantes: '), nsatisfies(Options1,gafas,ResultOptions), writeln(ResultOptions),delete(gafas,Conditions,ResultConditions),writeln(ResultConditions),game('PVP',ResultOptions,Options2,ResultConditions,Conditions2,Jug1,Jug2,2))
    )));
    
        writeln('Turno del jugador 2'),
        writeln('Preguntas restantes: '),
        %printList(Conditions),
        writeln('Elija su pregunta: '),
        read(Pregunta),

        (Pregunta = 'chico' -> (
          chico(Jug1) ->
            writeln('Correcto'),writeln('Personajes restantes: '), satisfies(Options1,chico,ResultOptions), writeln(ResultOptions),delete(chico,Conditions,ResultConditions),writeln(ResultConditions),game('PVP',Options1,ResultOptions,Conditions1,ResultConditions,Jug1,Jug2,1);
            writeln('Error'),writeln('Personajes restantes: '), satisfies(Options1,chica,ResultOptions), writeln(ResultOptions),delete(chico,Conditions,ResultConditions),writeln(ResultConditions),game('PVP',Options1,ResultOptions,Conditions1,ResultConditions,Jug1,Jug2,1));
        (Pregunta = 'chica' -> (
          chica(Jug1) ->
            writeln('Correcto'),writeln('Personajes restantes: '), satisfies(Options1,chica,ResultOptions), writeln(ResultOptions),delete(chica,Conditions,ResultConditions),writeln(ResultConditions),game('PVP',Options1,ResultOptions,Conditions1,ResultConditions,Jug1,Jug2,1);
            writeln('Error'),writeln('Personajes restantes: '), satisfies(Options1,chico,ResultOptions), writeln(ResultOptions),delete(chica,Conditions,ResultConditions),writeln(ResultConditions),game('PVP',Options1,ResultOptions,Conditions1,ResultConditions,Jug1,Jug2,1));
        (Pregunta = 'gafas' -> (
          gafas(Jug1) ->
            writeln('Correcto'),writeln('Personajes restantes: '), satisfies(Options1,gafas,ResultOptions), writeln(ResultOptions),delete(gafas,Conditions,ResultConditions),writeln(ResultConditions),game('PVP',Options1,ResultOptions,Conditions1,ResultConditions,Jug1,Jug2,1);
            writeln('Error'),writeln('Personajes restantes: '), nsatisfies(Options1,gafas,ResultOptions), writeln(ResultOptions),delete(gafas,Conditions,ResultConditions),writeln(ResultConditions),game('PVP',Options1,ResultOptions,Conditions1,ResultConditions,Jug1,Jug2,1))
    )))).
  



  

jugar:-
  modo(X),
  createList(Options,Man,Women),
  conditionList(Conditions),
  chooseCharacter(Jug1),
  chooseCharacter(Jug2),
  writeln(Jug1),
  writeln(Jug2),
  game(X,Options,Options,Conditions,Conditions,Jug1,Jug2,1).



  %delete('chico',Conditions,ResultConditions),writeln(ResultConditions)
%  createList(Options,Man,Women,Condiciones),
% copy(Options,Jugador1),
% copy(Options,Jugador2),
%  random_member(X,Condiciones),
%  satisfies(Options,X,R),
%  write('X = '),
%  write(X),
%  nl,
%  write('R = '),
%  write(R),
%  nl,
%  write('Options = '),
%  write(Options).%
```

I feel that it may have something to do with the functions satisfies/3 and nsatisfies/3, which returns a new list with the elements of a first one that satisfy (or dont in nsatisfies) a certain condition C which is set inside the predicate (satisfies(List,Condition,ResultList)).
EDIT: I am getting until the recursive call of game, going inside the function, and when player is different from one just goes back a redo satisfies/3.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: That's a pretty large program. Can you provide a smaller example that demonstrates the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a bunch of errors in your code.

It also seems you are essentially repeating snippets of code instead of creating some procedures and calling them and that makes your program a little large and difficult to follow.

I found at least these problems:

- You are calling `delete/3` with the first two parameters swapped. So, for example, instead of `delete(chico,Conditions,ResultConditions)` you should write `delete(Conditions, chico, ResultConditions)`.
- In the second branch (when Player=2) you copy and pasted the same code from Player=1 changing some variables, but forgot to change others. For example when you call delete you pass `Conditions` instead of `Conditions2` and pass  `Options2` instead of `Options` to `satisfies/3`.